# Which breed of dog is recommend for a beginner?

Tags: dogs

Which breed of dog is recommend for a beginner dog keeper ?

Type of breed that should not be very much expensive and should have good health life span.

Comment: You need to specify few more things like: do you spend more time at home or outside? How much free time do you typical have?  Are you an outdoor/ very active person and willing include outdoor activities time with your dog or not, because different dogs have different needs?  What type of house are you living in because different breeds have different spatial requirements?

Comment: Weekdays i spend most of my time in office but at weekends i am at home and sometime going out. I live in flat.

Comment: There is no private garden thing in my flat / house but there is a big public garden next to my building where i can take my dog for walking or something.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather have this as a comment, not enough points.

The first dog that I got, was a border collie mix with a lab. I was told that each breed has their own average health problem. Mix breeds don't cure it, but it gives a lesser chance of development. Which usually gives a longer health span. With that being said. Keep him/her exercised and eating healthy and they will live longer too!

Another thing I was taught, the darker the inside of the mouth, the smarter your furry friend will be. I want to say this is a myth. But, every dog I've met, that has had a darker inner mouth... Have been real quick learners.

Don't forget that it truly does matter the size of house or yard you have. It should be part of the decision, to the size of animal you want.

Hope this helps a little. I know someone else will leave a better answer and I hope they do. ;)